# Candy Machine V2 Testing on Devnet....reset?

Tags: blockchain, solana, nft, metaplex, candy-machine

Hope everyone is great!

This might be a silly question but just wanted to be sure as i'm seeing few mixed reviews on this. I've got candy machine up and running, all settings work including the whitelist function. Did couple test mints from an initial amount of 10. I'm now down to 2 nfts left to mint and was wondering if there was a way to add new assets or preferable reset/reverify the upload of 10 images/assets so i can test again without having to create a new candy machine. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately Candymachine doesn't offer these types of resets, you also can't add additional assets to a candymachine after it's been uploaded to either. You'll need to recreate another Candymachine to do additional tests.

Comment: Hi Tony,  cheers for clarifying this. lol yea I was really hoping for a work around. Thanks